# how to make auto complete field same as text field?

Tags: android

I make a autocomplete text field but It display only base line .I saw that editfield in phone is rectangular box .But in device it display simple base line as shown in image could you please tell me how I will make rectangle[image] so that it look same as edit text field

It should look like that a rectangle with border black and user enter the text in that rectangle ..
here is my code..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:text="@string/chooseStation"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/item_buttonId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/okButton" />

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/item_autoComplete"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

        android:textColor="#000000" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, create xml in your `drawable` folder, called, for example, `edit_text_background.xml`, like this:

```
<item android:state_focused="true"><layer-list>
        <item><shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <corners android:radius="5dp" />

                <solid android:color="#999999" />
            </shape></item>
        <item android:bottom="2dp" android:left="2dp" android:right="2dp" android:top="2dp"><shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <corners android:radius="5dp" />

                <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
            </shape></item>
    </layer-list></item>
<item><layer-list>
        <item><shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <corners android:radius="5dp" />

                <solid android:color="#CCCCCC" />
            </shape></item>
        <item android:bottom="2dp" android:left="2dp" android:right="2dp" android:top="2dp"><shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <corners android:radius="5dp" />

                <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
            </shape></item>
    </layer-list></item>
```

Then set it as a background of your AutoCompleteTextView:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/item_autoComplete"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_background"
    android:textColor="#000000" />
```